# Chrome give ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error when trying to upload file using FileUpload helper in WebMatrix

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I've created a photo gallery using the Gallery template in WebMatrix. Everything seems to work fine except that I get this ERR_CONNECTION_RESET whenever I try to upload a large file. I've tried with 12 Kb file and the app works fine but I get the reset error when trying to upload a 25 Kb file. Setting maxRequestLength to 51200 and executionTimeout to 3600 also didn't help.
Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of threads on the ASP.NET forums about this error (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET); not sure if any of those would help you resolve your issue. For example, there's this:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1526998.aspx/1

Some things to ascertain, anyway:

Same problem in other/every browser?
Does the issue manifest locally when you test, or only in a deployed site?

Sorry not to have anything more concrete to offer.